# Can a Hexblade warlock/Battle Master fighter use Armor of Hexes to make an attack miss, then use Riposte to attack after the enemy misses?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, warlock, combat-maneuver, stacking

My DM allowed me to create a tabaxi warlock/fighter, taking three levels in [Battle Master fighter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/fighter#BattleMaster) before my character's nature of curiosity led me into a pact with the [Hexblade warlock patron](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/warlock#TheHexblade). I now have a question that neither of us can find an answer to:

Can I use my Riposte maneuver in conjunction with my Armor of Hexes?

The Hexblade's 10th-level Armor of Hexes feature (XGtE, p. 56) states:

> If the target cursed by your Hexblade’s Curse hits you with an attack roll, you can use your reaction to roll a d6. On a 4 or higher, the attack instead misses you, regardless of its roll.

The Battle Master's Riposte maneuver (PHB, p. 74) states:

> When a creature misses you with a melee attack, you can use your reaction and expend one superiority die to make a melee weapon attack against the creature. If you hit, you add the superiority die to the attack’s damage roll.

**Can these two abilities stack, allowing my Tabaxi Hexblade to make an attack miss using Armor of Hexes and Riposte to make a melee attack using the Tabaxi's claws?**

We both know that we can make the rules of the game do as we please within reason, but we both would like to know what a by the book rules lawyer would rule in the use of these to reactions together.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

### No

Both of them requires reaction to use. You only have one reaction per turn, so you can only use either, but not both.

Comment: There's a reason 5e has the "Action economy" - and stacking abilities like these are exactly why it's there.